# OpenLayers 3 Interaction Style Conflict with ol.feature.setStyle

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

In OpenLayers 3, if I set a features style with `setStyle(...insert style...)`, the default interactions style with `ol.interaction.select` no longer appear.  If I try to define a style or style function like so:

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    style: ...insert style here...
});
map.addInteraction(select);
```

It will not work.  If I remove my custom style set with `ol.feature.setStyle(...insert style...)`, it works fine.  Does this make sense?  I wonder if setting a features style with `setStyle()` somehow overwrites the default interaction styles...

Any clues?

Comment: I think `ol.interaction.selection#style` should overwrite `ol.Feature#setStyle` even because it's a temporary overlay feature. Maybe you create a ticket on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the style or style function when instantiating the `ol.interaction.select`, I just used the `select` event to handle the selected and deselected styles.

```
var select = ol.interaction.select();
select.on('select', function (e) {
    if(e.selected.length > 0) {
        e.selected[0].setStyle(...insert selected style here...);
    }

    if(e.deselected.length > 0) {
        e.deselected[0].setStyle(..insert original style here...);
    }
});
```

For some reason, when originally defining the style of a feature with `setStyle`, you cannot use the constructor style or style function when creating the interaction.  This above works fine, but it's a little extra code.